# return double value of string passed

Tags: java, parsing, return, double

Create a method called parseEqn which will receive 1 String variable and return the double value of the expression passed to it.

```
parseEqn("123+23") → 146.0
parseEqn("3+5") → 8.0
parseEqn("3-5") → -2.0
```

this is what i have so far:

```
public double parseEqn(String str) {
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"+-/*%",true);
   String first = st.nextToken();
   String op = st.nextToken();
   String second = st.nextToken();

   double ff = Double.parseDouble(first);
   double ss = Double.parseDouble(second);

   double answer;

   if (op.equals("+")){
   answer= ff+ss;}
   else if (op.equals("-")){
   answer= ff-ss;}
   else if (op.equals("/")){
   answer= ff/ss;}
   else (op.equals("*")){
   answer= ff*ss;}

   return answer;
```

1. I keep getting the error Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator ArrayInitializer" to complete ArrayInitializerAssignement....
   what does that mean?
2. what do i need to do to my loop in order for it to work? i can manually input say ff+ss and the method will work just fine, but i cant seem to create a loop to check which operator is in the string for me and then pass the answer back.

note: im on a time crunch and would really appreciate help. a straight forward answer/explanation would be so helpful... not those super vague "oh its not hard..." type of thing...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for adding the Java tag, Wabs, for Emilio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine just Little modifications.

Check last Condition.

```
else if(op.equals("*")){answer= ff*ss;}
```

and Initialize `double answer` to 0.

Just in case for checking

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class Car {
    public double parseEqn(String str) {
           StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"+-/*%",true);
           String first = st.nextToken();
           String op = st.nextToken();
           String second = st.nextToken();
           double ff = Double.parseDouble(first);
           double ss = Double.parseDouble(second);
           double answer = 0;
           if (op.equals("+")){
           answer= ff+ss;}
           else if (op.equals("-")){
           answer= ff-ss;}
           else if (op.equals("/")){
           answer= ff/ss;}
           else if(op.equals("*")){
           answer= ff*ss;}
           return answer;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Car c = new Car();
        System.out.println(c.parseEqn("123+23"));
        System.out.println(c.parseEqn("3+5"));
        System.out.println(c.parseEqn("3-5"));
        /* Output From Console
         * 
         * 146.0
        8.0
        -2.0*/
    }
}
```